# Delphi: How to check if MySQL is installed on windows machine

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm developing an installer for my program for Windows OS.

I'd like the installer to check if MySQL is already installed and if it isn't silently install MySQL before installation is over.

How can I check if MySQL is already on the computer with delphi?

Comment: Are you requiring a MySQL server or just the client to be on the machine?

Comment: I'd hate any software that would silently try to install a dtabase server on my machine.

Comment: @SimonM I think the first place would be the registry...

Comment: @Mchl if this silent install is required and the user(s) are not computer savvy, then this would actually spare a lot of fuss..

Comment: So, is this a Delphi question, or an installer question? What installer tool are you using?

Comment: @Dorin Duminica: I believe that's how MicroSoft approaches it's customers. 'We know better what they need'. Anyway: lookinf for `mysqld` process in processlist as well as checking port `3306` are some ideas, none of them foolproof however.

Comment: @Mchl, what would your preference be? Make each customer acquire and install the *same* database software manually? And then field support calls when something goes wrong, but since you weren't in control of the installation, you have no idea how to troubleshoot your customers' issues? My company's software requires a database server, so we include it with the rest of the software. Makes things *much* easier for everyone.

Comment: Just don't make it a quiet install. Keep the customer informed.

Comment: what we do is we inform them that we are going to install, and the user has choice to decide to want or not, but once he choose yes, our installer installs it silently, which results in a uniform progress bar :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for this registry entry for MySQL if present
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB`
If you have MySQL installed then this entry should be present.

If you need some thing more, then check for the service if its present

```
    function ServiceIsPresent(sMachine, sService: PChar): Boolean;
    var
      SCManHandle, SvcHandle: SC_Handle;
    begin
      // Open service manager handle.
      SCManHandle := OpenSCManager(sMachine, nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
      if (SCManHandle > 0) then
      begin
        SvcHandle := OpenService(SCManHandle, sService, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
        // if Service installed
        if (SvcHandle > 0) then
          begin   
            Result := True;
            CloseServiceHandle(SvcHandle);
          end;
        else
            Result := False; 
        CloseServiceHandle(SCManHandle);
      end;
    end;
```

function call

```
  ServiceGetStatus(nil,'MySQL');
```

I have picked up this service name from my registry entries
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services`
But be careful while using service check because some people might have different service names for MySQL service.
As in my case I have 2 installations of MySQL hence 2 services are present MySQL,MySQL501.
Hence it will be bit tedious to find out the correct service name.

Comment: `try Result := SvcHandle <> 0; finally CloseServiceHandle(SCManHandle);` might be shorter. You could optionally close handle of the service manager as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Regarding MySQL server:**

1. As @Shirish11 sayd, you can check `HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB`. But that does not guarantee anything, as this registry key is optional. MySQL really does not require any "complex" installation procedure, like SQL Server. You can download MySQL as an installer, as just a ZIP archive. In last case the registry key will be not created. The similar with services. Using `mysqld.exe --install Kitty --defaults-file=c:\mysql.cfg` command line you can create MySQL service with Kitty name. Or even a service may be not created at all.
2. The MySQL server may be installed not locally, but on a different host. And be administrated by a dedicated DBA. So, you may not need to check / install server at all. Just not your task. If your application is going to install a local server, which will be used only by "this" workstation, then use MySQL Embedded.
3. In general, you should ask the user about MySQL installation, eg "Do you have MySQL server installed ?". And if user answers "yes", then you can ask him for login parameters (host, port, database, user name, password). If not, then you can suggest him to download it and install, to avoid licensing issues. Because you have to have a license, purchased from Oracle, to distribute the MySQL Server installer with your software.

**Regarding MySQL client:**

1. There is no other signs, that `libmysql.dll` is "installed", than the `libmysql.dll` presence. You can check for `libmysql.dll` at Windows folder, at `PATH` folders. More simple - you can always put it with your EXE.
2. If you are using dbExpress, then you should use specific `libmysql.dll` version, supported by EMBT dbExpress driver. So, again, better to put it with your EXE.
3. See note (3) regarding server licensing. It applies to client too.

Comment: I found your answer very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mind you `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB` can remain in registry even on uninstall of MySQL. What gets removed is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.1` but since we do not know the `MySQL Server 5.1` part in advance, its not easy to go for this approach. Moreover MySQL need not be installed as such.

What is possible is to check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MySQL\ImagePath` and then see if the path specified by the value exists. The second part is important because MySQL need not remove the service key during uninstallation if service is already turned off. So this registry value can remain even after uninstallation. So the best option is to get the path of the executable from the above mentioned registry and then see if the mysqld.exe or (whatever it is) exists. MySQL is not installed if either the registry value doesn't exist or if the file doesnt exist. The catch here is that this logic fails if MySQL is installed but not configured to start its service (which means there is no key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MySQL`). But thats trivial, since running MySQL installations will anyway have it and most machines will have MySQL running. Now even if the installed MySQL is not configured to have a service, its quite okay to install another version of your MySQL and register your service first.

I'm unsure of a perfect solution, the reason being MySQL being not a proprietary software. I mean anyone can bundle MySQL and install in their own flavours. For example, wampserver comes with their own MySQL. Client machines most certainly wont have servers installed that way, but we can not rule out the option and we may not want another MySQL instance (Note that a separate instance of MySQL runs fine along with MySQL in wamp server). What I do is check the above, if I did not find, I check for the image path of wamp service, like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\wampmysqld\ImagePath`. It depends on the server you have on a machine.